# EditText doesn't wrap_content

Tags: android, android-edittext

I can't seem to get my EditText's width to wrap_content. By that I mean to have the EditTexts width the same size as the text/hint inside it

This is a snippet of my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1,2,3" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bill Total" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etBill"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="0.00"
                android:textSize="14sp" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    ...
</TableLayout>
```

Since I am new here I can't post pictures so here is a [layout editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu8Hs.jpg)

Comment: I would try removing `android:layout_weight="1"`. I don't believe `TableLayout` has a `weight` property which could be giving you problems. And if it does, it isn't being used correctly. I guess maybe it does since `TableRow extends LinearLayout` but I still don't think you want that in there

Comment: Also, I think you want to change your `width` of your `TableRow` to `wrap_content`

Comment: Why would changing the width of the table row cause the edit text to wrap its contents? Wouldn't it just shorten the width of the table row ? Just Curious

Answer (score 4):

The attribute android:ems sets the width of the EditText field. Since you have set it to 10, you will always see a field that can accommodate 10 characters. So removing android:ems should help.

Answer (score 2):

I think to fix your problem you should remove `android:layout_weight="1"`. It doesn't seem to be needed in this situation. When you do use that you want to set your `width` to `0dp` for a `horizontal layout` and `height` to `0dp` for a `vertical` layout.

Changing your `width` of `TableRow` to `wrap_content` should give you what you want.

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBill"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bill Total" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etBill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="0.00"
            android:textSize="14sp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
</TableRow>
```

[According to the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)

> The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.

Comment: Just curiuos but why does wrap_content work. Won't it just limit the width of the table row and just limit the space of the elements in the table row?

Comment: Isn't that what you want? Maybe I'm confused by your question. Did you try it?

Comment: Why do you have `stretchColumns`? Also, column indices start with 0 like an `Array`. That may effect it, I don't know